# Перевод расстояний в дюйм

Tags: visual-basic, visual-studio-2012

Мне нужно напечатать таблицу перевода расстояний в дюймах для значений от 1 до 10 с шагом 1.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Один дюйм - это 25,4 мм. Сделайте таблицу пересчёта тупо в Excel.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Дело в том, что времени учить бейсик нет (ради одной задачи). Понимаю, что это сугубо лично мои проблемы, но все же надеялся найти понимание. Excel не подходит, условие задачи: написать именно в бейсике.

Comment: >>именно в бейсике ===  В *VS* тоже не получится на чистом *Basic*, там применяется VB.Net, В *Excel* можно написать макрос на *VBA*.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение:

```
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sm As String    '  объявление 
    Dim inch As Single    ' переменных
    Dim I As Integer
    sm = 1
    For I = 1 To 10 Step 1
      inch = sm * 2.54      ' пересчет
      MsgBox(Str(sm) + " | " + Str(inch)) ' вывод результата
      sm = sm + 1
    Next I
  End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: "нужно напечатать таблицу" - ваше решение печатает таблицу?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, сработает ли на *VS*, в *VBA* можно проще:

```
Sub Main()
Dim inch As Single
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
      inch = i * 2.54  ' пересчет
      MsgBox i & " | " & inch ' вывод результата
    Next i
End Sub
```

Для отбражения (печати) результата в редакторе *VBA* в окне *Immediate* изменить оператор в строке вывода результата:

```
Debug.Print i & " | " & inch
```

В дополнение - микрокалькулятор )

```
Sub Main2()
Dim i As Integer
    i = Val(InputBox("Впишите размер, кратный целому дюйму"))
    MsgBox i & " | " & i * 2.54
End Sub
```

Comment: "нужно напечатать таблицу" - ваше решение печатает таблицу?

Comment: Автор показал код, который ему подходит: пошаговое отображение результата. Это - вариант. *MsgBox* можно заменить на *Debug.Print*. Добавлю в ответ

Comment: То что ТС запостил ответ, еще не значит, что этот ответ правильный или подходит к вопросу.